# xslt 1 why doesn't my attribute value show in browser

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

**Environment: XSLT 1.0 and an Internet browser**

Two questions, if I may:
1. Like what the subject says, why is my attribute field1 value not showing in browser?
2. How would I check in a condition if @field1 and/or @field2 even exists?

**The problem**
When I open XML file in browser the page is blank, and I was expecting "one"

**XSL**

```
  <!---look at playground/stackoverflow/callvsapply example -->
  <xsl:template match="/data/leve1/level2/level3/target">
    <xsl:value-of select="@field1"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="get_attributes_in_hierarchy.xslt"?>
<data>
  <level1>
    <level2>
      <level3>
        <target field1="one" field2="two"/>
      </level3>
    </level2>
  </level1>
</data>
```

Comment: you are correct, thanks. Updated.

Comment: _"Environment: XSLT 1.0 and an Internet browser"_ -- local computer or served over an HTTP connection?  If the latter, how have you verified the browser is finding and retrieving the XSL?  Checked with Wireshark?

Comment: This is on a local computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct a typo in your XSL file :

```
<xsl:template match="/data/leve1/level2/level3/target">
```

Change to:

```
<xsl:template match="/data/level1/level2/level3/target">
```

As for testing if a field or attribute exists [Michael Kay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46104791/2261424) is correct, you would test on the name of the tag or attribute:

```
<xsl:if test="@field1 or @field2">...</xsl:if> <!-- this tests if attributes field1 or field2 exist -->
```

Then it's just a question using `or` or `and`, depending on the condition you want to check. And if you want an alternative answer in the case the field or attribute doesn't exist, you would use:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@field1">
        <xsl:text>Attribute field1 exists</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>Attribute field1 doesn't exist</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:choose>
```

Comment: @Rod Glad to hear it. But don't edit that correction into your question, as that kind of invalidates the question.

Comment: That resolved it, what is the best way to check if either attributes exist before using it? Attributes field1 and field2

Comment: @Rod Answered your second question, let me know if it answered it well.

Answer (score 2):

Some browsers, depending on security settings, refuse to run an XSLT stylesheet loaded from local filestore rather than loaded from an HTTP connection.

There will typically be messages on the browser's developer console explaining what happened.

Second question: to test if `@field` exists, use `<xsl:if test="@field">...</xsl:if>` assuming the current context is the element on which `@field` is defined.

Comment: I don't think it's the browser because I have another example working fine so it must be my xsl. There are actually 2 attributes I want to check for `field1` and/or `field2`.